# How to install gmp 4.3.2 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, gcc, install-from-source

I want to install gcc-4.4.3,for which I have to install gmp 4.3.2.
When I run:

```
./configure
make
```

I get this error. Can you help me?

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3'
Making all in tests
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests'
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests'
Making all in devel
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/devel'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/devel'
Making all in mpn
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/mpn'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/mpn'
Making all in mpz
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/mpz'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/mpz'
Making all in mpq
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/mpq'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/mpq'
Making all in mpf
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/mpf'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/mpf'
Making all in rand
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/rand'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/rand'
Making all in misc
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/misc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/misc'
Making all in cxx
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/cxx'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/cxx'
Making all in mpbsd
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/mpbsd'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests/mpbsd'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tests'
Making all in mpn
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/mpn'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/mpn'
Making all in mpz
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/mpz'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/mpz'
Making all in mpq
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/mpq'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/mpq'
Making all in mpf
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/mpf'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/mpf'
Making all in printf
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/printf'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/printf'
Making all in scanf
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/scanf'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/scanf'
Making all in cxx
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/cxx'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/cxx'
Making all in mpbsd
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/mpbsd'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/mpbsd'
Making all in demos
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/demos'
Making all in calc
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/demos/calc'
make  all-am
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/demos/calc'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/demos/calc'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/demos/calc'
Making all in expr
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/demos/expr'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/demos/expr'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/demos'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/demos'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/demos'
Making all in tune
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tune'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/tune'
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Downloads/gmp-4.2.3'
```

Comment: Uh, there is no error. There is nothing to be done because you probably already ran make once before. Try: `make clean` and then `make install` to check.

Answer (score 0):

There are no errors in this compile log. The "Nothing to be done for ..." messages mean that everything that needs to be compiled in the folder is already compiled (i.e. during a previous call to make)

The next step is usually to run the command:

```
sudo make install
```

to install the compiled libraries in a place where your system sees them (usually it will copy them in /usr/local/lib/)